# Saving the state of multiple views in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, savestate

I have a fragment, with several views. Two of them are custom: let's call them `FrameLayoutA` and `FrameLayoutB`. Issue is that `FrameLayoutB` does not save it's state when I return back to the fragment.

There's no `onSaveInstanceState`/`onRestoreInstanceState`/`setRetainInstance`/`onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`/`getLastNonConfigurationInstance` method called/overloaded nor in `FrameLayoutA`/`FrameLayoutB` classes nor in fragment's class.

Can't find reason why one view's state is saved and the other's is not. Any ideas? Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**

Stopped debugger at `onCreateView()` and apparently my restored value is in `inflater`->`mChildFragment`->`mSavedViewState`. `inflater` is of type `org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater`. Still looking for the answer why some views are saved but not others.

**UPDATE:**

So there are two my custom views, which has inflated same layout inside them. Layout has EditTexts with ids declared. So `View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState()` is restoring values on both views from values in the second view. So when I come back to the fragment, both my custom views has same values.

Comment: Make sure your view-s IDs are unique, maybe you have the same IDs and view can overwrite the previously saved values.

Comment: Debugging further and noticed that those values are saved in `inflater`. Updating question.

Comment: Well, I think, this is the root cause: I have two views of `FrameLayoutB`, and the second one has different state, so fields which I'm filling in `b1` are not visible in `b2`, so this should be the cause why `b1` view's state is overriden by empty `b2` state. Will confirm soon.

Comment: ok. looks like I found it. I had to save state manually, but disable automatic state saving for it's child views. Will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you want change the fragment, you make this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .addToBackStack(Fragment.class.getName())
                .**add**(R.id.content_fragment, fragment, Fragment.class.getName())
                .commit();
```

Call "add" instead of "replace" and when you return to the original fragment the state of the fragment it is ok.

This work for me, hope its help :)